# Interceptors(XYZ extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter) is not called for 405 responses

Tags: rest, interceptor

I have an GET but when someone calls with POST it gives me 405 method not supported which is correct. But it does not call the Interceptors.
The interceptors are called for 404 response but not for 405.
Trying to understand why is that

```
@GetMapping("/helloworld")
public String sayHelloWorld() {
   return "Hello World";
}
```